# New programmer work rate and expectations

Tags: php

I'm a new graduate and yave just started working a few weeks past as a web programmer. I've kind of been thrown in at the deepend and have been put straight on a project that appears on the face of it to be relatively simple, but there a lot of little intricacies that are making it quite difficult.

What sort of work rate will employers be expecting a new graduate to work at? My employer hasn't said anything but I feel like I am taking much longer than they anticipated - perhaps even regretting that the have employed me in the first place. Also, I am asking for help with logic and some best ways to tackle some problems and I also feel they think I should know more than I should. Again what would an employer be expecting from the level of a recent graduate.

I want to be as good as I can and learn as much as possible but I constantly feel under pressure as I keep thinkin I should be getting through mug more work than I currently am. Is this a common feeling in new programmers and how would my employer approach it if I wasn't performing up to their expectations. Like I said, nothing had been mentioned but I do feel they are wondering why they bothered to hire me.

Some advice on this from experienced developers would be great.

Comment: simple show your boss this question and it will be answered, I assure you nothing bad will come of it :)

Comment: Realistically you cant be expected to know much about specifics of certain technologies right out of school, and project management will usually account for that in hours delegated for you to accomplish tasks. You are likely to be billed at a much lower rate then more experienced developers on your team. Just make sure you use all resources available to you (Stack Overflow, The Google, and most importantly Other Team members), because any issue you run into is likely to have been encountered before. Just keep at it and before you know it new developers will be coming to you for help.

Answer (score 1):

"Rate" is a hard thing to quantify when talking about software - as you note, some simple things aren't easy, and some complicated things aren't hard. In general, the most important thing is to *communicate* with your employer. You may be afraid to talk about the problems, but it's much easier to talk about them now than to keep your mouth shut and only announce problems when your project is due.